# What factors affect the address of the stack on Linux?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, x86, stack-overflow

ASLR is one. What about if it's disabled? Is the start address of the stack the same across distros, kernel versions, what?

Does having different environmental vars change the addresses of objects further up the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not about to go comparing many different kernel versions, but in the latest development kernel (4.0), the loader for ELF binaries (`load_elf_binary` in `fs/binfmt_elf.c`) initializes the user stack at an architecture-dependent address (defined by the `STACK_TOP` constant) if ASLR is disabled. On some architectures, `STACK_TOP` is a fixed address, but on many, it depends on the "personality" (or "execution domain") of the current process.

Yes, the environment variables and command-line arguments are pushed on the user stack before the loaded program is run, so they will affect the user stack pointer as seen by the process right after `exec`.